# Docker Compose demo from official website question

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I am new to docker and I am studying : [Docker compose demo](https://docs.docker.com/compose/gettingstarted/).(python & redis)

According to the document, I successfully ran the service, But I want to know exactly how python connects to redis,As doc says:

[image]

But How do I check the host name of the redis container?

The container process is as follows:

```
docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                    NAMES
ec3eb988c705        redis:alpine        "docker-entrypoint.s…"   14 minutes ago      Up 10 minutes       6379/tcp                 composetest_redis_1
795a7e933d72        composetest_web     "flask run"              14 minutes ago      Up 10 minutes       0.0.0.0:5000->5000/tcp   composetest_web_1
```

I try to :

```
docker exec -it ec3e /bin/sh
/data # cat /etc/hostname 
ec3eb988c705
/data #
```

Looks like the hostname isn't redis?

Can someone tell me how they communicate with each other? I know that these two containers are in the same network, But I don't understand their mechanism.

Comment: [Networking in Compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/) has a reasonable explanation of this.  The name of each block in the `docker-compose.yml` `services:` section is usable as a host name by other containers.

Comment: Thank u very much！@DavidMaze

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That’s handled by the docker-compose process. Have a look in your `docket-compose.yml` file:

```
services:
  web:
    build: .
    ports:
      - "5000:5000"
  redis:
    image: "redis:alpine"
```

By default, the docker server name will be the key under `services`, so the server name   `redis` is established there.

Comment: Thanks!  I would appreciate it if you could just briefly elaborate on the mechanism behind it

Comment: docker-compose is the mechanism. It creates a local docker network that the services (containers, servers) defined in your `docker-compose.yml` are attached to, using the host names specified in the yaml file. You could do the same thing manually by first creating the docker network; then spinning up each container via docker run and specifying the docker network to use, and so on. docker-compose is just a convenience that does all those steps for you.

Comment: Thanks! I wonder why I went into the redis container and `cat /etc/hostname`,shouldn't there be `redis` instead of `id of container`.

Comment: No, because the virtual host name aka service name isn’t the same as the OS host name. Docker does a lot of things for you. You want each container to address the others by a fixed name, not a variable ID.

Comment: If I’ve answered your question, please click he check mark.